# Sound is not played instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I have a react project with a socket connection to a server. When a message is received, a sound (ping) should play. This is my code:

```
    socket.on('order', (data) => {
      let order = JSON.parse(data);
      dispatch({ type: 'PUSH_ORDER', payload: { order } });
      const audio = new Audio('/admin/assets/ping.wav');
      audio.play();
    });
```

When an order is received, it's pushed to the redux store and displayed, and the 'ping' sound is played. The problem is, it sometimes takes up to 5 seconds before the ping sound is played, even though the order is already on the screen.

It's for a pub where people can order through their online menucard.

Is there a possibility, like a callback or so, that when an order is received, the sound is played, and AFTER the sound is played, the order is pushed to the redux store. Something like this:

```
    socket.on('order', (data) => {
      let order = JSON.parse(data);
      const audio = new Audio('/admin/assets/ping.wav');
      audio.play(() => {
        // callback function when sound has played
        dispatch({ type: 'PUSH_ORDER', payload: { order } }););
      });
```

Comment: There's an event called `canplay`; you can use that to determine when the sound is ready to be played. You might also want to consider preloading the sound, which should prevent the delay.

Comment: Also move `const audio = new Audio('/admin/assets/ping.wav');` outside of the socket. You can make this global and play it.